# How to prove this iterative convergence of trigonometric functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Consider the set of sequences $ S=\{\{s_n\}_{n \ge 0}\mid s_n \in \{-1,+1\}\} $

For any set: $ s=\{s_n \}_{n \ge 0}\in S$, we define the sequence
$$ c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{s_0s_1 \dots s_k}{2^k}$$

Now, please prove a iterative formula：

$$ 2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}c_n\right)= s_0\sqrt{2+s_1\sqrt{2+s_2\sqrt{2+\dots+s_{n-1} \sqrt{2+s_n\sqrt{2}}}}}$$

NOTE: This question is from Yu Pin's Mathematical Analysis Lecture Notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use induction on all sequences of length $n$.

For length $1$ we have $2\sin(\frac{\pi}4 s_0) = s_0$, but actually $2\sin(\frac{\pi}4 s_0) = s_0 \sqrt 2$, so there's a slight error in the question - $s_n$ should be multiplied by $\sqrt 2$.

We have a sequence $s_0, s_1, ..., s_n$, let's look at $s_1, s_2, ..., s_n$. That sequence has some $c'_{n-1}$, and we have $c_n = s_0 (1 + \frac{1}2 c'_{n-1})$. So we want to prove
$$2 \sin(s_0 \frac{\pi}4 (1 + \frac{1}2 c'_{n-1})) = s_0 \sqrt{2 + 2\sin(\frac{\pi}4 c'_{n-1})}$$
Since $s_0 \in \{-1, 1\}$, we have $\sin(s_0 x) = s_0 \sin(x)$, so we just need to prove
$$2 \sin(\frac{\pi}4 + \frac{\pi}8 x) = \sqrt{2 + 2\sin(\frac{\pi}4 x)}$$
for the range $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.
We have $\sin(\frac{\pi}4 + \frac\pi8 x) = \sin(\frac{\pi}4) \cos(\frac\pi8x) + \cos(\frac{\pi}4) \sin(\frac\pi8x)$. But $\sin(\frac\pi4)=\cos(\frac\pi4)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, so our equation is just $\cos(\frac\pi8x)+\sin(\frac\pi8x)=\sqrt{1+\sin(\frac\pi4x)}$. Now $\sin(2 \frac\pi8 x) = (\sin(\frac\pi8x) + \cos(\frac\pi8))^2 - 1$, and we get $\cos(\frac\pi8x)+\sin(\frac\pi8x) = |\cos(\frac\pi8x)+\sin(\frac\pi8x)|$ or $\cos(\frac\pi8x)+\sin(\frac\pi8x) \geq 0$, which is true in particular for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.